# Why is jQuery dependency not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm extending core Classy theme so I have included my JavaScript code in `theme.libraries.yml` file like this:

```
js:
  js/blogger-list.js: {}
dependencies:
  - core/jquery
```

but still browser console shows error: jQuery is not defined

blogger-list.js is really simple:

```
(function ($) {
  $(".views-col a").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background','red');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I'm using Drupal 8

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

First of all: DON'T EDIT ANY CORE FILE! EVER!!! Simply create a [sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme) or a very simple module to add your custom stuff.

---

I doubt a little bit that it really is this exact file that raises that error. But if so (your `theme.libraries.yml` looks incomplete somehow), please try to follow the docs as close as possible and use `Drupal.behaviors` to add JS functionality. See [JavaScript API overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview).

**MYMODULE/MYTHEME.libraries.yml**

```
foobar:
  js:
    js/blogger-list.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
```

**js/blogger-list.js**

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.YOUR-VIEW-ID-OR-WHATEVER', context).once('myCustomBehavior').each(function () {

        $(".views-col a").hover(function () {
          $(this).css('background', 'red');
        });

      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

And last but not least don't forget to attach your library to a render array or your theme's info file. See [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme).